# Different time delay with different images

Tags: javascript

I need to rotate images on different time interval, like 1st image should be of 10 sec, second of 20sec timers etc. Please anyone can help me in this. I have this script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgs3 = new Array("../webroot/img/1.jpg", "../webroot/img/2.gif", "../webroot/img/3.gif");
var lnks3 = new Array("www.a.com", "www.b.com", "www.c.com");
var alt3 = new Array("StarBid", "Happy Winners", "Special Offer");
var currentAd3 = 0;
var imgCt3 = 3;

function cycle3() {
    if (currentAd3 == imgCt3) {
        currentAd3 = 0;
    }
    var banner3 = document.getElementById('adBanner3');
    var link3 = document.getElementById('adLink3');
    banner3.src = imgs3[currentAd3]
    banner3.alt = alt3[currentAd3] document.getElementById('adLink3').href = lnks3[currentAd3]
    currentAd3++;
}
window.setInterval("cycle3()", 10000);​
<script>
```

Comment: `banner3.alt = alt3[currentAd3] document.get...` is not valid Javascript. Also consider using a single array of objects for the data, each object can have url, alt, and src properties, instead of 3 separate arrays that you need to maintain the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle I created:
http://jsfiddle.net/cEUZq/14/

Replace the images with the ones you want to display.  Add as many images as you like. The variable `times` is an array which contains the number of seconds for each picture to be displayed.  Let me know if you need any help.

This requires jQuery.

Comment: It's somewhat limited because the intervals must each be a multiple of 1 second. Repeated `setTimeout()` would be better.

Comment: agreed.  I had modified a one-liner slideshow I had saved without putting much more into it.